# Yii проблема с ajax пагинацией

Tags: jquery, cgridview, pagination, php, yii

Здравствуйте, в моем шаблоне требуется выводить пагинацию отдельно от CGridView. Я сделал этот таким [образом](http://pastebin.com/2PZ4j6MF), но теперь пагинация работает без ajax, вопрос как поправить jquery обработчик для пагинатора? или как вообще решить эту проблему ? :)

Answer (score 1):

1. находим файл jquery.yiigridview.js  - лежит в папке assets виджета CGridView.
2. там ищем методы которые мы можем задействовать - на беглом просмотре

   $.fn.yiiGridView.update = function (id, options) {
           $('#' + id).yiiGridView('update', options);

это походу то что вам надо.

1. На кнопки пагинатора вешаем свои функции на события onClick - чтоб запрос не уходил на сервак. В кратце функция должна передать переменные пагинатроа (станица, кол-во на странице и тд) в $.fn.yiiGridView.update .

как то так

Comment: Только заметил нативное решение 'updateSelector'=>'#yw1 li a', все работает, но пагинация не меняет классы, т.е. нажал на 2ую страницу, и на эту цифру должен повесится класс active - а он не вешается : (

Comment: оказывается так и должно быть : )

Comment: @dogmar так вопрос решен или не решен? Если решен, то отметьте правильный ответ/добавьте правильный ответ и отметьте его. Чтоб закрыть вопрос